# Detect when user selects text in a textarea

Tags: javascript

How to detect when user selects text in a textarea with JS?
I used jQuery-fieldselection ,but it works only if the `range.text` is putted into a pre tag.It doesn't work with div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `select` event. It works for `<textarea>` and `<input type="text">` elements in all mainstream browsers. Support is not universal for other elements.

```
document.getElementById("your_textarea").onselect = function() {
    alert("Select");
};
```